# Android Studio BootstrapButton text unable to align center

Tags: android

I am unable to make bootstrap button bb_text_alignment center and can't find any solution. And also when I put android:layout_height="match_parent", the button fill up entire space. Below are my config:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:bootstrapbutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:singleLine="false" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            bootstrapbutton:bb_type="primary"
            bootstrapbutton:bb_size="large"
            bootstrapbutton:bb_text_alignment="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

reagrds,
Mark